# How to deny access from just one host in a domain

Tags: apache-httpd, authorization

In apache 2.4.6, I would like to deny access to an entire domain, except for one (or maybe more) specific hosts (and the rest of the world). sort of like:

```
Require not host xxx.com   ## nobody from this domain gets in...
Require host blah.xxx.com  ## --except for this one host in xxx.com
Require all granted        ## and the rest of the world!
```

Can this even be done?  If so, can anyone describe the seemingly magic combination of RequireAny/All/None to accomplish this?

Above and beyond this, I would like to duplicate the logic with other blacklisted domains (possibly with their own exceptions).

Comment: Why deny access to no one? It is like a firewall chain. Lookup how they work you will get it.

Comment: Right, I was experimenting with that as well, but hoping to use the newer directives...

Comment: I see. Well, I hope you find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

- I would make sure your Order directive is set Allow,Deny.
- Then I would:

  ```
  Allow all granted        ## and the rest of the world!
  Allow host blah.xxx.com  ## --except for this one host in xxx.com
  Deny not host xxx.com   ## nobody from this domain gets in...
  ```

But:

```
Allow host blah.xxx.com  ## --except for this one host in xxx.com
```

Is pointless because it is allowed by the first.

Because:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from example.org
Deny from foo.example.org
```

Order meant to limit down to host not from domain up to host.

So in short because of the way order works, what you want is really not possible, with just apache. Because the last directive will always override the rest.

However, you could then block the host you want, by not allowing it through the firewall.

Because the firewall is first, it is not even going to make it to the service to need filtering.

Comment: Yes, I'm beginning to see that this may just be impossible to configure.  I am not a firewall expert, but I will consult with one to see how I might do this at that layer.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, easy to do -- mod_rewrite actually solves this problem nicely!

Comment: O, cool that is nice to know. Thanks for the added info. @BillT